# Implementing a barcode scanner in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, barcode-scanner

I am trying to implement a barcode scanner using Angular 4, using this plugin - https://github.com/isonet/angular-barcode-scanner.

In my `scanner.component.ts` page I have;

```
    import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import 'angular-barcode-scanner';
...
```

In my `app.module.ts` file;

```
  ....
import { BarcodeScanner} from 'angular-barcode-scanner';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
        LoginModule,
        SignupModule,
        DashboardModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        BarcodeScanner
      ],
      providers: [
        DataService,
        TokenService
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

And then in my `scanner.component.html` file;

```
<barcode-scanner separator-char="separatorChar" trigger-char="triggerChar" scan-callback="scanCallback"
                trigger-callback="triggerCallback"></barcode-scanner>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, I get the following errors in console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at Object.defineProperty.value (angular-barcode-scanner.js:1)
    at r (angular-barcode-scanner.js:1)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (angular-barcode-scanner.js:1)
    at angular-barcode-scanner.js:1
    at t (angular-barcode-scanner.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular-barcode-scanner.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 0689b0e…:52)
    at Object.152 (bsElement.routes.ts:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 0689b0e…:52)
    at Object.413 (chart.module.ts:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 0689b0e…:52)
    at Object.153 (chart.component.ts:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 0689b0e…:52)
    at Object.155 (dashboard.component.ts:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 0689b0e…:52)
Object.defineProperty.value @ angular-barcode-scanner.js:1
r @ angular-barcode-scanner.js:1
Object.defineProperty.value @ angular-barcode-scanner.js:1
(anonymous) @ angular-barcode-scanner.js:1
t @ angular-barcode-scanner.js:1
(anonymous) @ angular-barcode-scanner.js:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0689b0e…:52
152 @ bsElement.routes.ts:9
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0689b0e…:52
413 @ chart.module.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0689b0e…:52
153 @ chart.component.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0689b0e…:52
155 @ dashboard.component.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0689b0e…:52
405 @ app.module.ts:40
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0689b0e…:52
404 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0689b0e…:52
424 @ table.module.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0689b0e…:52
393 @ src async:7
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0689b0e…:52
733 @ main.bundle.js:2545
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0689b0e…:52
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 0689b0e…:23
(anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1
bundle.js:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: ng is not defined
    at N (bundle.js:19)
    at VueComponent.ready (bundle.js:15)
    at VueComponent.LN.M._callHook (bundle.js:5)
    at VueComponent.z (bundle.js:5)
    at VueComponent.N (bundle.js:5)
    at VueComponent.M.$emit (bundle.js:5)
    at VueComponent.LN.M._callHook (bundle.js:5)
    at z (bundle.js:5)
    at VueComponent.M.$before (bundle.js:5)
    at CN.transition (bundle.js:6)
    at CN.mountComponent (bundle.js:6)
    at bundle.js:6
    at bundle.js:6
    at N (bundle.js:4)
    at ON.QN.M._resolveComponent (bundle.js:5)
N @ bundle.js:19
ready @ bundle.js:15
LN.M._callHook @ bundle.js:5
z @ bundle.js:5
N @ bundle.js:5
M.$emit @ bundle.js:5
LN.M._callHook @ bundle.js:5
z @ bundle.js:5
M.$before @ bundle.js:5
transition @ bundle.js:6
mountComponent @ bundle.js:6
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:6
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:6
N @ bundle.js:4
QN.M._resolveComponent @ bundle.js:5
resolveComponent @ bundle.js:6
setComponent @ bundle.js:6
bind @ bundle.js:6
CN._bind @ bundle.js:6
Gz @ bundle.js:4
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:4
M._compile @ bundle.js:5
M.$mount @ bundle.js:5
M._init @ bundle.js:4
Y.M._init @ bundle.js:19
ON @ bundle.js:5
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:3
zone.js:155 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geAdapter' of undefined
    at WebSocket._ws.onopen (eval at M.exports (bundle.js:3), <anonymous>:97:46)
    at WebSocket.wrapFn [as _onopen] (zone.js:851)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:262)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:151)
    at WebSocket.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:332)
_ws.onopen @ VM53541:97
wrapFn @ zone.js:851
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:262
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:151
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:332
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

[`QuaggaJS`](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS) is a barcode-scanner entirely written in JavaScript supporting real-time localization and decoding of various types of barcodes such as `EAN, CODE 128, CODE 39, EAN 8, UPC-A, UPC-C, I2of5, 2of5, CODE 93 and CODABAR`. The library is also capable of using getUserMedia to get direct access to the user's camera stream. Although the code relies on heavy image-processing even recent smartphones are capable of locating and decoding barcodes in real-time.

Using QuaggaJS, [`Angular example`](https://github.com/LaurentSouchet-Orange/Angular-readbarcode-quagga) for barcode scanner

NPM Angular module for angular barcode scanner:

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Quagga from 'quagga';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  barcode = '';
  barcodeResult;
  configQuagga = {
    inputStream: {
      name: 'Live',
      type: 'LiveStream',
      target: '#inputBarcode',
      constraints: {
        width: { min: 640 },
        height: { min: 480 },
        aspectRatio: { min: 1, max: 100 },
        facingMode: 'environment', // or user
      },
      singleChannel: false // true: only the red color-channel is read
    },
    locator: {
      patchSize: 'medium',
      halfSample: true
    },
    locate: true,
    numOfWorkers: 4,
    decoder: {
      readers: ['code_128_reader']
    }
  };
  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Barcode: initialization');
  }

  testChangeValues() {
    this.barcode = 'Code-barres bidon : 0123456789';
  }

  startScanner() {
    this.barcode = '';
    this.ref.detectChanges();

    Quagga.onProcessed((result) => this.onProcessed(result));

    Quagga.onDetected((result) => this.logCode(result));

    Quagga.init(this.configQuagga, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      Quagga.start();
      console.log('Barcode: initialization finished. Ready to start');
    });


  }

  private onProcessed(result: any) {
    const drawingCtx = Quagga.canvas.ctx.overlay;
    const drawingCanvas = Quagga.canvas.dom.overlay;

    if (result) {
      if (result.boxes) {
        drawingCtx.clearRect(0, 0, parseInt(drawingCanvas.getAttribute('width'), 10), parseInt(drawingCanvas.getAttribute('height'), 10));
        result.boxes.filter(function (box) {
          return box !== result.box;
        }).forEach(function (box) {
          Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(box, { x: 0, y: 1 }, drawingCtx, { color: 'green', lineWidth: 2 });
        });
      }

      if (result.box) {
        Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(result.box, { x: 0, y: 1 }, drawingCtx, { color: '#00F', lineWidth: 2 });
      }

      if (result.codeResult && result.codeResult.code) {
        Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(result.line, { x: 'x', y: 'y' }, drawingCtx, { color: 'red', lineWidth: 3 });
      }
    }
  }

  private logCode(result) {
    const code = result.codeResult.code;
   
    if (this.barcode !== code) {
      this.barcode = 'Code-barres EAN : ' + code;
      this.barcodeResult=result.codeResult;
      this.ref.detectChanges();
      console.log(this.barcode);
      console.log(this.barcodeResult);

      // this.barcodeValue = result.codeResult.code;
      // this.barcodeResult=result.codeResult
      // console.log("this.barcodeValue",this.barcodeValue)

      console.log("JSON.stringify(result.codeResult)",JSON.stringify(result.codeResult))
      console.log("Result",result)
      console.log("JSON.stringify(result)",JSON.stringify(result))
      // console.log("this.barcodeResult",this.barcodeResult.json())
      Quagga.stop();
    }

  }

}
```

```css
#interactive.viewport {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

#interactive.viewport>canvas,
#interactive.viewport>video {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

canvas.drawing,
canvas.drawingBuffer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
h1 {
    color: white;
    background-color: #ff6600;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* TODO style temporaire en attendant de migrer dans un autre composant */
    margin: auto !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ngb-alert type="info" [dismissible]="false">
      <strong>Je scanne</strong> le code-barres pour voir les ODR.
  </ngb-alert>
</div>
<div *ngIf="barcode">
  <ngb-alert type="success" [dismissible]="false">
      {{ barcode }}
  </ngb-alert>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="startScanner()">
  Démarrer le scan du code-barres
</button>

<div class="input-group">
 
  <div id="inputBarcode" style="position: static">
      <div id="interactive" class="viewport"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[`GitHub Reference Link`](https://github.com/julienboulay/ngx-barcode-scanner)

Comment: The link to the github repo is dead. Do you have a new link?

Comment: This link is working https://github.com/julienboulay/ngx-barcode-scanner

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/isonet/angular-barcode-scanner is an AngularJS(V1) App and you seem to be building Angular(V4 may be?) app. I don't think you can 
 use `<barcode-scanner>` just like that.

Comment: Yeah Angular V4... I'm struggling to find any V2 / V4 versions

Comment: Looks like that is for generating barcodes, I want to read them using a camera (iOS / Android) / webcam

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Should have read the description before suggesting. http://developer.telerik.com/featured/scanning-barcodes-nativescript-angular-2/ may be something that might help if you're using NativeScript. If not, then probably you can refer to this and make your own Angular2 Component and may be open source it :) as an Angular2 Module.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has released the [Shape Detection API](https://web.dev/shape-detection) in their version 83 and this includes the Barcode Detector API. So if you are only focused on Chrome users, like in my case, I would suggest the [ng-barcode-detector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-barcode-detector) package.

Comment: I get error, "Uncaught DOMException: Barcode detection service unavailable." on firing the detect(). Looks like chrome does not support this API on chrome 84. Can anyone help, if this is only for Mobile ?

Answer (score 0):

**Angular 10** you can use this Module `ngx-barcode-scanner`

**Doc:** https://github.com/julienboulay/ngx-barcode-scanner

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from "@angular/core";
import { BarecodeScannerLivestreamComponent } from "ngx-barcode-scanner";

@Component({
  selector: "demo-app",
  template: `
    <barcode-scanner-livestream
      type="code_128"
      (valueChanges)="onValueChanges($event)"
      (started)="(onStarted)"
    ></barcode-scanner-livestream>
    <div [hidden]="!barcodeValue">
      {{ barcodeValue }}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class Demo implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(BarecodeScannerLivestreamComponent)
  barecodeScanner: BarecodeScannerLivestreamComponent;

  barcodeValue;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.barecodeScanner.start();
  }

  onValueChanges(result) {
    this.barcodeValue = result.codeResult.code;
  }

  onStarted(started) {
    console.log(started);
  }
}
```