# Implementing barcode scanner in angular 4 application for android phone

Tags: barcode, scanning

I like to implement barcode scanning module in my angular 4 application.
I am using ngx-barcode npm module to generate the barcodes which is working fine.

My project requirement is to scan as well therefore, If anyone knows how to scan barcode using android camera will be a great help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45219565/implementing-a-barcode-scanner-in-angular-4

Answer (score 1):

[`QuaggaJS`][1] is a barcode-scanner entirely written in JavaScript supporting real-time localization and decoding of various types of barcodes such as `EAN, CODE 128, CODE 39, EAN 8, UPC-A, UPC-C, I2of5, 2of5, CODE 93 and CODABAR`. The library is also capable of using getUserMedia to get direct access to the user's camera stream. Although the code relies on heavy image-processing even recent smartphones are capable of locating and decoding barcodes in real-time.

Using QuaggaJS, [`Angular example`][2] for barcode scanner

NPM Angular module for angular barcode scanner:
[1]: https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS
[2]: https://github.com/LaurentSouchet-Orange/Angular-readbarcode-quagga
[3]: https://github.com/julienboulay/ngx-barcode-scanner

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Quagga from 'quagga';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  barcode = '';
  barcodeResult;
  configQuagga = {
    inputStream: {
      name: 'Live',
      type: 'LiveStream',
      target: '#inputBarcode',
      constraints: {
        width: { min: 640 },
        height: { min: 480 },
        aspectRatio: { min: 1, max: 2 }, // sane aspect ratios?
        facingMode: 'environment', // or user
      },
      singleChannel: false // true: only the red color-channel is read
    },
    locator: {
      patchSize: 'medium',
      halfSample: true
    },
    locate: true,
    numOfWorkers: 4,
    decoder: {
      readers: ['code_128_reader']
    }
  };
  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Barcode: initialization');
  }

  testChangeValues() {
    this.barcode = 'Code-barres bidon : 0123456789';
  }

  startScanner() {
    this.barcode = '';
    this.ref.detectChanges();

    Quagga.onProcessed((result) => this.onProcessed(result));

    Quagga.onDetected((result) => this.logCode(result));

    Quagga.init(this.configQuagga, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      Quagga.start();
      console.log('Barcode: initialization finished. Ready to start');
    });


  }

  private onProcessed(result: any) {
    const drawingCtx = Quagga.canvas.ctx.overlay;
    const drawingCanvas = Quagga.canvas.dom.overlay;

    if (result) {
      if (result.boxes) {
        drawingCtx.clearRect(0, 0, parseInt(drawingCanvas.getAttribute('width'), 10), parseInt(drawingCanvas.getAttribute('height'), 10));
        result.boxes.filter(function (box) {
          return box !== result.box;
        }).forEach(function (box) {
          Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(box, { x: 0, y: 1 }, drawingCtx, { color: 'green', lineWidth: 2 });
        });
      }

      if (result.box) {
        Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(result.box, { x: 0, y: 1 }, drawingCtx, { color: '#00F', lineWidth: 2 });
      }

      if (result.codeResult && result.codeResult.code) {
        Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(result.line, { x: 'x', y: 'y' }, drawingCtx, { color: 'red', lineWidth: 3 });
      }
    }
  }

  private logCode(result) {
    const code = result.codeResult.code;
   
    if (this.barcode !== code) {
      this.barcode = 'Code-barres EAN : ' + code;
      this.barcodeResult=result.codeResult;
      this.ref.detectChanges();
      console.log(this.barcode);
      console.log(this.barcodeResult);

      // this.barcodeValue = result.codeResult.code;
      // this.barcodeResult=result.codeResult
      // console.log("this.barcodeValue",this.barcodeValue)

      console.log("JSON.stringify(result.codeResult)",JSON.stringify(result.codeResult))
      console.log("Result",result)
      console.log("JSON.stringify(result)",JSON.stringify(result))
      // console.log("this.barcodeResult",this.barcodeResult.json())
      Quagga.stop();
    }

  }

}
```

```css
#interactive.viewport {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

#interactive.viewport>canvas,
#interactive.viewport>video {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

canvas.drawing,
canvas.drawingBuffer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
h1 {
    color: white;
    background-color: #ff6600;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* TODO style temporaire en attendant de migrer dans un autre composant */
    margin: auto !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ngb-alert type="info" [dismissible]="false">
      <strong>Je scanne</strong> le code-barres pour voir les ODR.
  </ngb-alert>
</div>
<div *ngIf="barcode">
  <ngb-alert type="success" [dismissible]="false">
      {{ barcode }}
  </ngb-alert>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="startScanner()">
  Démarrer le scan du code-barres
</button>

<div class="input-group">
 
  <div id="inputBarcode" style="position: static">
      <div id="interactive" class="viewport"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[`GitHub Reference Link`][3]

Comment: I've submitted an edit request to this to change the max aspectRatio from 100 to 2, as 100 results in very incorrect results in iOS 14+